# Why are SE Chat Users Sending *These* Questions to WPSE?

Tags: discussion

See here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30321/sourcing-content-and-images-for-office-interior-design-blog

The gist of the question:

> a) The ideas to blog about, how do they find out about these office interior designs b) how they get the content for them, how do they know what to write about each one, do they need permission etc, c) if i am interested in doing a blog on the same office interior design as them, how can I get information )and permission from the company that done the office interior design) on the office interior design so i can blog about it and also how do i get the images and stuff.

And note the comment:

> I asked on the chat where to put this question and they all said here so sorry but I did ask fellow stack members where I should post the question and this was the most suitable place.

The user was displeased that I down-voted the question, but the question clearly has nothing to do with **WordPress**, and is clearly outside the scope of WPSE. Of course, I can understand why the user might be frustrated, if other SE users actually *directed* him to WPSE to ask this question.

So, *my questions*: why are SE Chat users directing such questions to WPSE, and what can we do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering there are entire StackExchange sites devoted to *users* of specific types of software rather than just *developers* and *administrators* of that software, I can see where the confusion comes from.  Other SE members likely see "WordPress Answers" and think "A site about all things WordPress" rather than "A site for WordPress developers and administrators."

Since he started with "I'm currently building a blog on WordPress," they probably thought this was the right place.

When you take a look at some of the other SE sites that are targeted towars *users* for example, you'll see that WPSE seems to be the exception, not the rule, for this kind of site.  We're targeted at developers, themers, and admins ... not merely at "enthusiasts."

### [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Ask Different is for **Apple enthusiasts** and **power users**. If you have a question about ...

- Apple hardware
- Apple software
- other Apple products or services
- third-party hardware and software for Apple products

and it is **not** about ...

- Apple Developer Programs or iTunes Connect
- programming, with the exception of AppleScript and Automator
- installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware
- a shopping or buying recommendation for hardware
- pre-release or beta software

... then you're in the right place to ask your question!

### [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq)

Android - Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people too using the Android operating system.

Android - Stack Exchange is **not** for programming questions. Please ask your developer questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: So, once again, I bring up the topic of our *defined scope*. Perhaps we should elaborate a bit more, similarly to your Apple reference? Should I start a new question for such discussion, or just let you mods take care of it as you see fit?

Comment: I should also note: the question itself was specific to *blogging* - i.e. *content generation* - and was entirely agnostic with respect to the CMS used to manage that content. So, even if our scope included *use* of WordPress, such a question would be outside of that scope.

Comment: I agree entirely. It's outside of the scope. But many non-WP people will read "I'm using WordPress to ..." and immediately think to point in our direction.  A question to further refine and define our scope would be very useful!

Comment: See [What should our FAQ contain](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-should-our-faq-contain). It's old, so needs some refresh, more votes and to be acted on after that.

Comment: @Rarst, thanks for linking that question. I've added some initial input. Should we perhaps summarize some of the on/off-topic suggestions in the question itself?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as uniform crowd of "SE chat users". Chat system is organized into multiple rooms and users usually group by in rooms that are associated with their sites.

Note that outside of WPSE site - network users are not guaranteed to know precisely scope of WPSE. For them it can just be something "about WordPress which is blogging thingie or something". Even in moderator room I am constantly being asked to clarify which question exactly do we deal with.

This was not asked in our room, I will try to track down (if possible) where conversation took place.